# Reference list value in Elementstyle

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid, datatrigger

after having found much help on stackoverflow, I am now struggling with a problem I could not find an answer for yet. My goal is the following:

I have a datagrid in a wpf/c# application filled with figures. Dependending on whether the figure is positive or negative, I want to change the foreground font to green or red. The itemsource for the datagrid is a list of my own class which includes the following elements:

- string description
- a list of 12 doubles called totalMoney

I have manually configured the columns for the datagrid so that the first shows the description, then the value of totalMoney[0], then totalMoney[1] and so on. After some searching, I found a way to change the foreground colour of the individual cells based on the values here on stackoverflow via a datatrigger method plus IValueConverter with the following code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding totalMoney[2], Converter={StaticResource money}}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding totalMoney[2], Converter={StaticResource money}}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding totalMoney[2], Converter={StaticResource money}}" Value="-1">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
 </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

However, as you see in the code, in WPF I have to reference the Binding to an individual item in my List (totalMoney[X]). I therefore have to manually set the style for each Column in my datagrid. As I want to use the style in several datagrids, this seems to me as highly unpractical.

My question is therefore - is it possible to define the style so that it changes depending on the value of a cell in general? Or is there maybe a completely different way to achieve my goal that I have overlooked?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, you could use the following style for all totalMoney[] columns ...

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="MoneyIndicatorStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                   Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                     Converter={StaticResource money}}"
                   Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger
                   Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                     Converter={StaticResource money}}"
                   Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger
                   Binding="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                     Converter={StaticResource money}}"
                   Value="-1">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
```

But here is a **potential catch**... if tommorrow you decide that the text of these textblocks is going to be a formatted currency like this... **$(1,00)** i.e. negative 100 dollars in accounting world, then the converter could have to cast this formatted string into a locale-neutral number i.e -100.00 and yield 0, 1 or -1 based on the current logic in converter.

Right now your converter is at ease because it receives a straightforward numeric value (totlaMoney[n]) from your model but using the above style it will rely on the `Text` displayed by the `Textblock`!

So the decision is yours.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that did the trick! It even works with my money class with the format "0,00 €", so it fits my purpose perfectly. So, thanks a lot :)